# Is column a discriminator?

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

If a user does something like this inside `OnModelCreating`:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<MyBaseEntity>.HasDiscriminiator(x => x.EntityType)
```

Outside `OnModelCreating`, is it possible to either get the full list of discriminator columns or check if a particular column was configured as discriminator?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In EF Core 3.x it can be obtained for a given [IEntityType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.ientitytype?view=efcore-3.1) using the [GetDiscriminatorProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entitytypeextensions.getdiscriminatorproperty?view=efcore-3.1) method, e.g.

```
var discriminatorProperty = dbContext.Model
    .FindEntityType(typeof(MyBaseEntity))
    .GetDiscriminatorProperty();
```

Some other useful extension methods are [GetDiscriminatorValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entitytypeextensions.getdiscriminatorvalue?view=efcore-3.1), [GetDerivedTypes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entitytypeextensions.getderivedtypes?view=efcore-3.1), [GetRootType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entitytypeextensions.getroottype?view=efcore-3.1) etc.